# Energy Consumed by my code in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, energy

I'm working in Ubuntu with some kind of functions and I would like to know how energy they consume but I haven't found a good tool for this, or at least make it run.
I have tried with:

- [Intel Energy Checker](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-energy-checker-sdk). But I can't make it run, I have some erros in the productivy_link.h and I haven't touch this file, only download it.
- [PowerTOP](https://01.org/powertop/) This tool works but with this you can only see  the discharge rate of your battery and this is not very 'exact' due to some processes of the OS can be executed automatically.

Could someone help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Did you checkd `pwrkap`? You can install it with (and the `gui` too):

```
sudo apt-get install pwrkap pwrkap-gui
```

You can also check this link: [powerstat: Power Consumption Calculator for Ubuntu Linux](http://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/02/powerstat-power-calculator-ubuntu-linux/)